# what is the open cv pts data type?

Tags: python, opencv

can any one help me to solve this problem ?
i'm flowing a tutorial and my code is the same of the instructor , the code should make a triangle area white ( area_of_interest ) and display it .

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lanes.py", line 32, in <module>
    cv2.imshow('result',region_of_interest(canny) )
  File "lanes.py", line 15, in region_of_interest
    cv2.fillPoly(mask , polygons , 255  )
TypeError: pts data type = 17 is not supported
```

code

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def canny(image): 
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image , cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY )
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray , (5,5) , 0 ) # each pixel intensity is the mean weight of the two adgacent ones
    canny = cv2.Canny(blur , 50 , 150 ) # 1:3 ratio 
    return canny 

def region_of_interest(image) : 
    height = image.shape[0] 
    polygons = np.array([[(200,height),(1100,height),550 ]])
    mask = np.zeros_like(image)
    cv2.fillPoly(mask , polygons , 255  )
    return mask 

color channel instead of all R,G,B channels

image = cv2.imread('test_image.jpg') # read an image as a 2 dimentional array of each pixle indintity
lane_image = np.copy(image)  # a copy of the image object ( array of numeric values ) 
canny = canny(lane_image)
cv2.imshow('result',region_of_interest(canny) )
cv2.waitKey()
```

i read previous answers but still can't solve the problem : \

Comment: This line seems to be strange: `polygons = np.array([[(200,height),(1100,height),550 ]])`. I guess, you wanted to set up three points, but the last one is no proper 2D point. Maybe, for testing just write `(550, 550)` instead of `550`. At least, you then have a proper array of points. What is the **actual** purpose of this line?

Comment: Thats it : D ! 
Thanks a lot @HansHire